# Formula Parse Error with Filter Function in Google Sheets

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am trying to use a formula that searches a sheet called All Data for 2 variables.  One is the store name and the other is the identifier payment method.  Only 2 options are available for payment method. The other thing is I want it to search for multiple locations and filter to one sheet.

A2 = Beverly
B2 = Stoneham

When I use this formula I get a parse error.  Any ideas on what the issue is with this?  When I use just one filter it works.  It seems to be when I add that other filter it errors out.

```
=filter('All Data'!A:K,('All Data'!$B:B=A2,'All Data'!$E:E="EGFL")+('All Data'!$B:B=B2,'All Data'!$E:E="EGFL"))
```

This works for pulling all data from the main sheet

```
=filter('All Data'!A:K,('All Data'!$B:B=B2)+('All Data'!$B:B=A2)+('All Data'!$B:B=C2)+('All Data'!$B:B=D2)+('All Data'!$B:B=E2)+('All Data'!$B:B=F2))
```

I have tried this

```
=filter('All Data'!A:K,('All Data'!$B:B=B2,'All Data'!$E:E="REPL")+('All Data'!$B:B=A2,'All Data'!$E:E="REPL")+('All Data'!$B:B=C2,'All Data'!$E:E="REPL")+('All Data'!$B:B=D2,'All Data'!$E:E="REPL")+('All Data'!$B:B=E2,'All Data'!$E:E="REPL")+('All Data'!$B:B=F2,'All Data'!$E:E="REPL"))
```

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
=QUERY({
 IFERROR(FILTER('All Data'!A:K, 'All Data'!B1:B=A2, 'All Data'!E1:E="EGFL"), 
 {"","","","","","","","","","",""}); 
 IFERROR(FILTER('All Data'!A:K, 'All Data'!B1:B=B2, 'All Data'!E1:E="EGFL"), 
 {"","","","","","","","","","",""})}, 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Error
In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows. This is what i get with your above formula...

Comment: Thank you for the response.. That worked.. Secondary issue... This throws an error as well =SUM(QUERY({
 IFERROR(FILTER('All Data'!K:K, 'All Data'!B1:B=B1, 'All Data'!E1:E="EGFL"), 
 {""}; 
 IFERROR(FILTER('All Data'!K:K, 'All Data'!B1:B=B2, 'All Data'!E1:E="EGFL"), 
 {""}}, 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0))))

Comment: try: `=SUM(IFERROR(QUERY({ 
 IFERROR(FILTER('All Data'!K:K, 'All Data'!B1:B=B1, 'All Data'!E1:E="EGFL"), {""}); 
 IFERROR(FILTER('All Data'!K:K, 'All Data'!B1:B=B2, 'All Data'!E1:E="EGFL"), {""})}, "where Col1 is not null", 0)))`